# gradle init project with specific struct

Tags: gradle, task, global, archetypes

I want create project with custom files for few project with equal struct, for example every project should have custom css files, example bootstrap.min.css in /webapp/css, custom login page in /webapp/html, and logo image in webapp/image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34yF8.png)
How can I do it? Gradle don't have archetypes generate. How can I create some "global" task? For example when I execute gradle createSimpleProject in any dir, it generate this custom project. Can I create this use gradle init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every directory is more or less a Gradle project - in particular an empty directory is an empty Gradle project. If you run `gradle tasks` inside an empty directory, you'll get list of tasks, including basic `init` tasks or `wrapper` task.

You can add to these tasks by setting up `init.gradle` file in your gradle directory (on Mac it's `~/.gradle/gradle.init`, for other platforms see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script)). Adding a task to root project will allow you to call it even in empty directory. Here's sample content of `init.gradle` file:

```
gradle.rootProject {
  task yourInit {
    group = "Helper"
    description = "Create structure for whatever project"
    doLast {
      println 'Create structure here'
    }
  }
}
```

Opening terminal in empty directory and running `gradle yourInit` will cause block in `doLast` to run in this directory. You can put directories and files generation there.